# Image mask animation in two stages – possible with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, animation, jquery-animate

I did a search and can’t find this exact question answered anywhere (please let me know if it has been and I’ve missed it!)

I’m trying to create an animation where four images are faded in over a background image in two stages – ideally using jQuery, and ideally jQuery which will work in IE8 and up.

It’s a little bit difficult to describe exactly the effect i’m intending to create, so I’ve done up an example gif animation to give a sense of it. The gif, obviously, loops the animation, but I’m only intending for it to load and play once, on page load. Check it out here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPr0D.gif

I’ve tried looking around for combinations of `.animate()` with image masking/revealing, which also blurs the edges of the image as they are revealed – but no luck so far!

If you have any ideas about the best way to proceed with this, I’d be very grateful to hear them.

Thanks.

(Edit! Alternatively, it would be possible to use the left-to-right `wipe` transition provided by the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/wipe.html), and layer up three jpegs, but in this case there would still need to be some way to blur the edges of the images as they swipe out)

Answer (score 0):

This method will only use jQuery animations and CSS.

You can simply have two divs on top of the one that has the background image. Set their initial width to zero and when the page loads, animate the width of the first one. Then use the callback function of that animation to animate the width of the second (the topmost) one.

To get the blurry effect - set the transparent blur gradient as an image or as another div background with height 100% and background repeating on Y axis. Do this for each of the two layer divs. They need to have higher z-index than the layer divs.

And lastly the guitars: they can be just the background images of each of the two layer divs, or even images, it's up to you. Just don't forget to make the top layer have a bigger z-index.

To clear it up, here is the pseudo structure:

```
<div> Main div that contains the bg image
    <div> First layer div with the first guitar image (Duo-Sonic)
        <div> Div (or <img>) with the blur image floating on the right
    </div>
    <div> Second layer div with the second guitar image and has a higher z-index than the first layer div (Jaguar)
        <div> Div (or <img>) with the blur image floating on the right
    </div>
</div>
```